# Choosing the best aggregation location measure

Tags: categorical-data, references, median, mean, model-comparison

I'm trying to analyze a granular dataset that is composed as follows:

```
Event   ID   Y   X
1       1    0   0.89
1       2    0   0.91
1       3    0   0.21
2       1    1   0.72
2       2    1   0.16
3       1    0   0.65
3       2    0   0.54
4       1    1   0.54
4       2    1   0.49
4       3    1   0.16
4       4    1   0.16
4       5    1   0.16
5       1    0   0.16
...
```

My goal is to aggregate data on the base of the *ID* variable, by taking the maximum value for the Y variable and considering among the different location measures available (simple average, geometric mean, trimmed mean, winsorized mean, median, mode,...) and running a simple logistic regression based on the following model:

$logit(P(Y_{i}=1))=\alpha + X_i\beta$

I would like to understand if it is possible to choose among such statistics not only on judgemental basis (for instance, I could choose the median simply because it is more robust as location measure in the case of outliers detection in the distribution of the variable *X*), but on statistical basis.

To this aim, do you know if it exists a statistical test to compare for difference between such location measures? Could you provide any references?

Alternatively, would it be correct to aggregate data on the base of each measure, running the logistic regression model described above and choose the best location measure on the base of the Akaike Information Criterion?

Here, for instance, the best location measure would be identified by choosing the model with the lowest AIC in absolute values.

Thanks all for any help!

Comment: linear model or logistic regression? Text say logistic model, but equation is linear model.

Comment: Hi @user158565! My idea was to run the test by implementing the logistic regression model, as written in the question. Could you suggest another way to represent the model in the equation, please?

Comment: Thanks for the changes @user158565!